# Gvim in UTF8 with Russian keyboard layout

Tags: vim, utf-8, internationalization, keyboard-layout

I am a big fan of vim and gvim. But whenever I write localization code in PHP and have to translate some strings (primarily in Russian), I have to open Notepad to translate all the entries. That kinda sucks, but so far I have not found out how to make gvim work in utf8 mode. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put these into your .vimrc:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8
```

you should now be able to play with the UTF8 files.

Comment: I used these settings. But then ALT key changed its behavior. Now pressing ALT key with some letter key inserts an accented character. Is there a way to disable this? I asked this question in superuser forum: http://superuser.com/questions/154491/utf-8-option-makes-alt-key-to-insert-accented-characters-in-vim-how-to-disable-i